# Pre release Apple iTunes connect error

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, coronasdk

hopefully link should show my iTunes connect page, if not, oh well...

[image]

I am having major issues with iTunes connect!
This is my first time uploading an app, and the pre release in iTunes connect is not working. According to the apple online Developer guide, there isn't a yellow "!" next to the build. And I should be able to submit my app for a beta app review, and I should be able to invite internal testers. Right now, I can't invite internal testers, it shows two external testers added, but they can't see anything in there test flight apps. I am building my apps with Corona sdk, and uploaded with application loader. I am using a Ad hoc Dist. Profile.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you check with Apple Store Provisioning profile? The link is showing Build: 2014.12.4. Please update it to 1.0 or something like that

Comment: Ok, I fixed the build thing, it now shows version 0.2.10. The yellow triangle and exclamation mark and other issues are still there. What type of provisioning profile should I be using ?

Comment: Did you validate your build before uploading to itunes? If no, please do that first.

Comment: How do I validate an app? I builit the app in corona sdk, and uploaded to iTunes connect via application loader, I don't think I valitaded it anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to follow these steps in order:

First add the devices to your TestFlight/iOS developer acc.
Then create App ID.
Then create your provisioning profile and make sure to update XCode to have it.

Adding devices later makes all invalid unless you update them (I find it easier to do redo rather than update).